# Git - list remote branches with their author names

Tags: git, cmd

Based on my search , the below 2 commands are supposed to give me remote branches with their author name. However, I get nothing in return - do you know why ?

I am using windows command prompt.

The below command returns : "Input file specified two times."

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' | sort -k5n -k2M -k3n -k4n
```

The below command returns nothing :

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)'
```

What should I do to list all active branches with their author names ?

Comment: What about git branch -av?

Comment: @Christoph, thanks for the reply. I am getting lots of branches with latest comments, but I am not getting author names. I wanted branch name, author name , and if possible creation date. Do I have to tweak the command you shared ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are trying to run a Unix-Command in a Windows `cmd` shell. The Windows `sort` does not understand the `-k5n` syntax. Try running it in the `bash` shell provided by Git For Windows and it will not print errors.

There is room for improvement though: `git for-each-ref` can sort itself:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)'
```

Next: You mentioned you want only remote branches. Actually you also get local branches, tags, notes and perhaps some more stuff. You can restrict it to remote branches:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' refs/remotes
```

Since there is no `sort` command any more you can run it in `cmd` again after adjusting the quoting of the `format` parameter (`cmd` and `bash` use different quoting semantics):

```
git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate --format="%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)" refs/remotes
```

Comment: I use this command to list all the remote branches in Azure DevOps, but it also list the branches being deleted (actually just being deleted). Any idea how to filter them out?

Comment: No idea because I don't know how Azure DevOps marks branches as deleted. This is nothing Git knows about: Either a branch (or ref) exists or not -- a "mark as deleted" state does not exists.
You may ask a separate question using an Azure and/or DevOps tags.

Comment: To get a nice tabular output on the last command when Authors sometimes only use one name, you can use the following: ```git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate --format="\"%(committerdate)\" %09 \"%(authorname)\" %09 \"%(refname)\"" refs/remotes | column -s"\"" -t```

Comment: As far as I know, my answer solves the problem of filtering out the remotely-deleted branches.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to put double quotes instead of simple :

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)" | sort -k5n -k2M -k3n -k4n
```

If it doesn't work, just try without the `sort` causing the error :

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer operates on the local repository, which isn't necessarily an accurate representation of what is actually on the remote.

Since the accepted answer requires bash on Windows, I figure bash is fair game.

As far as I know, the following answers the question more accurately than the accepted answer, because it actually lists (truly) remote branches, along with their authors, with no other caveats.

```bash
git fetch

git ls-remote --heads \
 | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' \
 | sed 's~refs/heads/~refs/remotes/origin/~' \
 | xargs git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)%09%(authorname)" {} \
 | sed 's~refs/remotes/origin/~~' \
 | sort
```

Breakdown:

- `git fetch`: from the remote, get the latest branch information (which is used by the subsequent `git for-each-ref` command)
- `git ls-remote --heads`: get remote branches
- `awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'`: extract just the branch paths
- `xargs git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)%09%(authorname)" {}`: feed the branch paths to `git for-each-ref` and query for branch path and author
- `sed 's~refs/remotes/origin/~~'`: remove some extra path prefix information that overly-complicates the branch names
- `sort`: sort the results, by branch name